# database mocking Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, falconframework

I am writing test cases for a file called api.py and app.py instantiated my app.

app.py

```
from d import db

def create():
    d = db()
    # here I create db instance and pass to my application
    api = API(d)
app = create()
```

api.py

```
from app import app
class API1:
    pass
class API2
    pass
```

I want to patch my database.

Below is my test file, here I setup my application in `setUp` once.

```
#from app.app import app doesn't work here
class TestCase(testing):
    @patch("/path/db")
    def setUp(self):
       # when I import my app here I am able to patch db but doesn't when I have import at file level
       from app.app import app
       self.app = app.create()
```

I am trying to patch whole db stuff to avoid setting up db and stuff for each test cases.
How do I patch when I import at file level?

Comment: You didn't give any real code and not a single test. How should we help?

Comment: Real problem is when I have import defined at file level, I can't mock db when I have same import inside `setUp` it works.

Comment: Still too abstract. But `@patch("/path/db")` is definitely not the right call.